# Expected ';' at end of declarations list

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to create a new Objective-C class in Xcode and am getting a couple of the above errors in the .m file.

```
#import "Query.h"

@implementation Query {

MPMediaQuery *query = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init]; //create new query



[[query addFilterPredicate: [MPMediaPropertyPredicate
                            predicateWithValue: @"Vampire Weekend"
                            forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtist]]; //filter out artists except for Vampire Weekend
// Sets the grouping type for the media query
[query setGroupingType: MPMediaGroupingAlbum]; //sort by album

NSArray *albums = [query collections];
for (MPMediaItemCollection *album in albums) {
    MPMediaItem *representativeItem = [album representativeItem];
    NSString *artistName =
    [representativeItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
    NSString *albumName =
    [representativeItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
    NSLog (@"%@ by %@", albumName, artistName);

    NSArray *songs = [album items];
    for (MPMediaItem *song in songs) {
        NSString *playCount = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlayCount];
        NSString *lastPlayed = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyLastPlayedDate];
        NSString *songTitle =
        [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];

        //NSString *info = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@ has been played %@ times.\n Last played %@.", songTitle, playCount, lastPlayed];
        NSLog(@"\n%@ has been played %@ times.\n Last played %@.", songTitle, playCount, lastPlayed);

    }
}
// Override point for customization after application launch.
[query release];

}

@end
```

Xcode freaks out and gives errors at line that I define an object, or try to use query (since it is undefined).

My header file is as follows (not complete, but I stopped to deal with this):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface Query : NSObject {
  MPMediaQuery *query;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MPMediaQuery *query;

@end
```

Comment: mipadi's answer is correct, but there's one more error in your code: The `@implementation` block should not be wrapped in curly braces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put your code inside a method -- you can't have it "loose" in the implementation.

Comment: Wow that was idiotic. Now I get only one error when I try to add the filter at the beginning that says "identifier expected". What does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the curly braces after the `@implementation`, and you need to put your code inside some method!

It should read something like:

```
@implementation Query

- (void)aMethod {
    // Code here
}

@end
```